# iOS 9 AVAssetDownloadURLSession crash

Tags: ios

Environment:
Xcode v9.1
Swift 4

I am trying to create an AVAssetDownloadURLSession to download the video asset from the background. However the app crash on iOS 9 due to the following reasons.

```
'NSGenericException', reason: 'Creating an AVAssetDownloadURLSession requires the com.apple.developer.media-asset-download entitlement'
```

Does anyone know how to fix the crash on iOS 9 (Simulator & Real device)? Many thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You can't. The availability annotation is incorrect: that API requires a private entitlement on iOS 9 so you can't use it.

You can call it on iOS 10 or later.